# PHP 5 to PHP 7 migration

Tags: php, migration

`set_magic_quotes_runtime` is a deprecated function. Migrating from PHP 5.3 to PHP 7.2

Will it create any issue?

[image]

Comment: Since the code disables magic quotes anyway, just remove those lines and you should be set.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you mean to say there is no need of replacement.

Comment: magic_quotes are removed from PHP 7 (which is the same as `off`) so unless you rely on magic quotes to be enabled, just removing those lines should be enough. Suggestion, remove the lines and test the application and you'll see it works or not?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you